# Tablet for movie watching: ZTE SPro2 or Yoga tab 3?

Tags: android, tablet, projector

I don't have a TV because I think they are ugly and require too much space. I like the idea of packing away the screen so it's not always there, in plain sight. However I still like to watch films, so I often just watch films on my laptop. I have an old projector, which I bought to watch films with. However I found the fan too loud, and I found it annoying to set up, Requiring many cables to power the projector, my laptop and the HiFi system. It takes a long time to turn on and then to turn off which was also annoying.

Recently I have come across two devices, that have the potential to solve some of these problems and are not too expensive.

1. The [ZTE SPro2](http://www.androidauthority.com/zte-spro-2-review-602653/) is primarily a projector but has a battery and android built in. It has 200 lumens and a high res screen, but when on battery it will only run at 100 lumens. It is difficult to source in the UK and I would have to buy it on ebay as an import. If it does not work as I expect, it will be hassle to return.
2. The [Yoga tab 3 Pro](http://www.androidauthority.com/lenovo-yoga-tab-3-pro-review-658663/) this is primarily a tablet but has a built in projector. The projector is only 50 lumens and 480p resolution projector, but the battery life is much better. I could probably watch 2 films on one charge. The main advantage is, that it's an ok tablet as well, which I might end up using a fair bit, although it's not something I really need or want (I wouldn't just buy an ipad for example). I can source this easily through amazon uk.

So to sum up I am looking for a device for occasional film watching that is nice and clean and which can be packed away when not in use.

My living room is quite bright, so I think for both devices it would work better in the winter. Has anyone had any experience comparing the brightness of the devices in real life? What do people think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yoga tab 3's 480p screen would be a pain to watch on. A 480p screen at 10" size is already terrible (80 ppi). The 480p screen would be ok for stuff like video conferencing or a presentation but would be very terrible for movies. The ZTE SPro 2 has a much better quality projector (720p). This will have the same pixel density as the yoga tab 3 when at 20" (78 ppi). These projectors are pretty dim so you will need a darker environment.